# Using regex in Mac OS X: why I have to add \ in {3, 5} ==> \{3, 5\} ...?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I am trying to find all files with no-extension in a particular folder, and after many attempts I finally came up with this regex statement:

> `ls | grep "\.[A-Za-z]\{3,5\}$"`

Why I have to start the occurrences around the {} with \, like escaping the sequence? Is there a way to use standard regex like this?

> `ls | grep "\.[A-Za-z]{3,5}$"`

I want, ultimately to get the opposite list of files with no-extension, but this non standard regex is making it hard for me to negate the result from the grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shell is ksh then you could list files in the current directory without an extension like this:

```
printf '%s\n' !(*.*)
```

Bash supports ksh extended globs when you enable them:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' !(*.*)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not need to *escape* the *curly-braces* with a *backslash* if you *form* the *command* properly.

In other words, when using a *RegRx* with `grep`, let it know the *search pattern* is a *RegEx* by using the `-E` *option*.

If you want an *inverse match* then use the `-v` *option* as well.

Example:

```
ls | grep -E -v '\.[A-Za-z]{0,5}$'
```

- Note I used `{0,5}$` instead of `{3,5}$` to account for any extension up to 5 characters. If you want to include files that might have a 1 or 2 character extensions, then use `{3,5}$` instead.

You can also use the following example:

```
ls | grep -E -v '\.[[:alpha:]]{0,5}$'
```

Sometimes a file extension can have numbers in them, so to account for that, use as an example:

```
ls | grep -E -v '\.[A-Za-z0-9]{0,5}$'
```

Or:

```
ls | grep -E -v '\.[[:alnum:]]{0,5}$'
```

**Note:** Some commands require the *options* to be passed individually, while others can be combined. In this case, `grep` does allow *options* to be concatenated. So in the example *commands*, `-E -v` can be expressed as `-Ev` or `-vE`, if you wish.